# algorithms directed graph and its sources

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Give a linear-time algorithm that takes as input a directed graph in adjacency list format, and outputs all of its sources.

i know that a source in a directed graph is a node that has no edges going into it.

i am really confused by this question can someone walk me through this problem, so i can see how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: can someone please help me with this problem, this is the only one im stuck on

Answer (score 1):

It would suffice to count the in-degrees of every vertex, and output those having in-degree zero.

Let $V$ be your set of vertices.  Let's assume each vertex is encoded by an integer.
You can start with a table $T$ with $|V|$ elements, where $T[i]$ will contain the 
in-degree of the $i$-th vertex of $V$.

> Initialize all values of $T$ to zero.
>
> For each $u \in V$ :
>
> > For each $u'$ in the list of neighbors of $u$ :
> >
> > > $T[u'] \gets T[u'] + 1$
> >
> > End for
>
> End for
>
> Output all $v$ such that $T[v] = 0$

Now you should be able to convince yourself that this runs in time $O(m + n)$, where $m$ is the number of arcs (directed edges) and $n = |V|$.